# reaching the goal number

Tags: python, numbers

I am a beginner so if this question sounds stupid/unclear or very easy , please bear with me.

How can I add a list of numbers together in order to reach a target number or get as close as possible? For example, here is a list of numbers: (2,3,4,7,20,25), goal = 105. The result should be this: (25,25,25,25,3,2). The order of given numbers matters; always start with the biggest number in the list and add them up in order get close to the given value, so it will choose the next digit to test.  the result could be also (20, 20, 20, 20, 25), which is not right in this case, because it doesn't follow the order of numbers. The algorithm only jump for the next number if it can feet otherwise can't jump.

Best M

Comment: 25+25+25+25+4= 104 != 105. So shouldn't the result be `(25,25,25,25,3,2)`?

Comment: Sounds like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem).

Comment: Isn't this just the old change-making problem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem

Comment: @mete No, not the Frobenius problem. The goal there is to figure out which number is the largest which cannot be attained with the given coefficients. This is much simpler.

Comment: @Rawing shouldn't the result actually be `[20, 20, 20, 20, 25]`?

Comment: OP: what is the proper result of `your_function((40,79), 80)` ?

Comment: "as few as possible numbers" / "get as close as possible" which criterion has higher priority? Is it allowed for the sum to be larger than the goal? "it always start from the biggest number in the list and add them up in order get more than given value" is this an attempt to solve the problem or is it part of the requirement?

Comment: the result should be  (25,25,25,25,3,2) and also order of numbers is matter - always starting with the biggest number in  the list.

Comment: This question looks like a better match for [CodeGolf.SE](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) than here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a dynamic-programming approach:

```
def fewest_items_closest_sum_with_repetition(items, goal):
    """
    Given an array of items
      where each item is 0 < item <= goal
      and each item can be used 0 to many times

    Find the highest achievable sum <= goal

    Return any shortest (fewest items) sequence
      which adds to that sum.
    """
    assert goal >= 0, "Invalid goal"
    # remove any duplicate or invalid items
    items = set(item for item in items if 0 < item <= goal)
    # sort descending (work with largest values first)
    items = sorted(items, reverse=True)

    # start with the no-item sequence
    best   = {0: []}
    active = {0: []}
    # while we have further seeds to work from
    while active:
        nactive = {}
        for item in items:
            for total, seq in active.items():
                # find next achievable sum
                ntotal = total + item
                # if it is a valid subgoal and has not already been found
                if (ntotal <= goal and ntotal not in best):
                    # save it
                    best[ntotal] = nactive[ntotal] = [item] + seq
                    if ntotal == goal:
                        # best possible solution has been found!
                        break
        active = nactive

    # return the best solution found
    return best[max(best)]
```

which then runs like

```
>>> fewest_items_closest_sum_with_repetition([2,3,4,7,20,25], 105)
[25, 20, 20, 20, 20]

>>> fewest_items_closest_sum_with_repetition((40,79), 80)
[40, 40]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l=(2,3,4,7,20,25)
goal = 105

a=max(l)
b=0
res=[]
while b<=goal-24:
    b+=a
    t=goal-b
    res.append(a)
    g=0
    for x in l:
        g+=x
        if g==t:
            res.append(x)
            res.append(g-x)
            break

print (res)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
[25, 25, 25, 25, 3, 2]
>>>
```

I found this solution, however, really annoyed me :-)! Tricky part is `while b<=goal-24:` , other codes are basic Python.

Comment: There are a few things wrong with this code: The hard-coded `goal-24` and `res.append(g-x)` (it's not guaranteed that `g-x` is one of `(2,3,4,7,20,25)`!).

Comment: `g-x` is guaranteed because I doing that when `g==t`

Comment: Note that the correct solution here is `[20, 20, 20, 20, 25]`

Comment: @AdamSmith He asking it with `max` value of list first?

Comment: It seemed to me that he's trying to find the fewest items to sum up to the goal, and was simply parroting the algorithm he felt would get there. I suppose I could be wrong

Comment: @AdamSmith Yes he is trying to find with `max` first, I mean first he want to sum `max` again and again untill close to `goal`

Comment: @sacma I think that's an XY problem. I'm *guessing* that what he really wants is to find how few terms sum up closest to `goal`, but I've left a clarifying comment on the question.

Comment: @AdamSmith Question is obviously not clear, maybe you are right about [20, 20, 20, 20, 25] , but it seems like he want to find it with `max` value first

Comment: The greedy solution for the coin change problem is `[25, 25, 25, 25, 3, 2]` while the optimal solution is `[20, 20, 20, 20, 25]` - but the OP wants `[25, 25, 25, 25, 4]` so either it is not the coin change problem or the question indeed suffers from the xy problem.

Comment: @PauloScardine True, however asker should give an explanation about her/his question..

Answer (score 0):

Is this right? I don't have time to test right now.

```
def solution(numbers, goal):
    curr = 0
    numbers = sorted(numbers)
    while curr < goal:
        if not numbers: break
        n = numbers.pop()
        while n + curr <= goal:
            yield n
            curr += n

list(solution([2,3,4,7,20,25], 105))
```

Results:

```
[25, 25, 25, 25, 4]
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Frobenius problem. That problem asks "given an equation of the form a1x1 + a2x2 + ... anxn = N, what is the largest number N which cannot be a solution to this equation". Also known as the "McNuggets problem" for the special case of 6a1 + 9a2 + 20a3 = N. (the solution to that special case is 43)

Comment: Ok, renamed (misread your comment as saying it was the name of the problem when in fact you were stating the contrary).

Comment: Thank you for playing along with my pedantic nature. :)

Answer (score 0):

If speed is not an issue, here's an ultimately correct response:

```
import itertools

def change_maker(coins, amount):
    for r in range(amount//max(coins), amount//min(coins)+1):
        possibilities = (combo for combo in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(coins, r) if sum(combo) == amount)
        try:
            result = next(possibilities)
        except StopIteration:
            # no solution with current r
            continue
        else:
            return result
```

This will always return the optimum result, but in some cases can calculate an ABSURD number of combinations to get there.

DEMO:

```
>>> coins = (2, 3, 4, 7, 20, 25)
>>> goals = 105
>>> print(change_maker(coins, goal))
[20, 20, 20, 20, 25]
```